# Remap function keys to the Pixelbook media keys

Tags: keyboard-layout, chromebook

I've installed kubuntu on a pixelbook and would like the media buttons to not act as the function keys. I'd prefer a gui program to remap them.

I tried to do it using xev and a few other tools, but most of the actions are increase brightness and stuff that I couldn't find keycodes for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make media keys work on a Chromebook natively running Ubuntu MATE 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451097/how-to-make-media-keys-work-on-a-chromebook-natively-running-ubuntu-mate-22-04). The same answer applied for Kubuntu, just open keyboard settings and switch layout.